# When does a QGIS .qix spatial index of a shapefile need to be re-created?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-index

I understand the basics of spatial indexes but would like to understand when exactly a spatial index would need to be re-created or updated?

The reason I ask is because when a folder was moved to a new drive on my computer rendering slowed down considerably for the shapefiles contained within it. Before moving they all had a spatial index created. After the move and after I realised the rendering had slowed I created new ones not really knowing if it would help but it seemed to work.

I use QGIS 2.18.20

Comment: Maybe the spatial index .qix file stores layer reference as absolute path.

Comment: Would changing the Save paths option to relative in the general options stop this?

Comment: .qix file does not store absolute paths. Your case is interesting but I fear it is hard to repeat the problem so it could be debugged.

Comment: Technically, shapefiles don't have a spatial index.  The specification doesn't dictate their presence or format, so they're not part of the format. GIS software packages do have spatial index *implementations* for shapefiles, but the Esri `.sbx`/`.sbx` is different than the QGIS `.qix`, so you really ought to specify which implementation more prominently in the question.